# Session does not save values between pages

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

I'm encountering a strange error that has been on and off throughout my entire coding process.

On every page, i require_once at the top of the page an authentication.php.

In there would be this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) 
{ 
    $_SESSION['auth'] = randString(); //this is my own method creating a random auth id
    $_SESSION['test'] = "Session is set and remembered.";   
}
```

However, my auth continues to generate a random id every refresh.

Around this point i discovered that my session stores a "PHPSESSID" in cookie form, and changed it to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])) 
{ 
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
}
else
{
    echo "hi";  
}
```

Though this changed my session id from changing every refresh, it never does echo 'hi', which comes to the conclusion that the session values aren't being stored.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: session must be start the top ......

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` needs to be called at the top of the page, even after the session has started.

Remove the `if` at the beginning: `if(!isset($_SESSION))`

Comment: Thank you for replying, but that doesn't seem to create any noticeable change :(

Answer (score 0):

if you don't call `session_start()` at the beginning of each page it will not store the session variable. If you're including this code in many pages, it should be safe to just call it again. I've never experienced any problems doing this. Just nix the first line and add `session_start()`

[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)